# HTTP Status 500 - in a spring program to display hellp world

Tags: spring

Below is the stack trace of the error:
type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet spring threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


root cause 

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArguments(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)[Ljava/lang/Class;
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.getRequiredTypeInfo(GenericConversionService.java:260)
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.addConverter(GenericConversionService.java:83)
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.addScalarConverters(DefaultConversionService.java:63)
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.addDefaultConverters(DefaultConversionService.java:54)
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.<init>(DefaultConversionService.java:43)
    org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.<init>(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:41)
    org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.<init>(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:41)
    org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.<init>(AbstractEnvironment.java:98)
    org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment.<init>(StandardEnvironment.java:54)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment.<init>(StandardServletEnvironment.java:44)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.createEnvironment(HttpServletBean.java:213)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.getEnvironment(HttpServletBean.java:203)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:126)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Being new to MVC architecture and spring...need help to resolve this!

Comment: List out the JARS you are using .

Comment: I am using following jar file- commons-logging-1.1.3.jar, jstl-1.2.jar, spring-aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar, spring-aspects-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar, spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar, spring-context-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar, spring-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar, spring-expression-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar, spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar, spring-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar

Answer (score 1):

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArguments(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)[Ljava/lang/Class;

I imagine that you just deployed on a server where spring-core version jar is different than the one against which you compiled. Check the server spring-core.jar and very likely GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArguments has Method as first parameter and not Class hence your exception

Comment: I understand that the issue can be because of difference in the versions of the jar files. but i have used the jars having same version. (commons-logging-1.1.3.jar, jstl-1.2.jar, spring-aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar, spring-aspects-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar, spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar, spring-context-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar, spring-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar, spring-expression-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar, spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar, spring-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar) Please tell me if I have missed out any. Thanks

Comment: Guys, it worked!!!
I actually missed out to include "spring-asm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar" to the WEB-INF/lib which then caused -java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/asm/ClassVisitor error. It ran successfully after importing the asm jar with correct version. 
Thanks for helping with my first Spring MVC program. :)

Comment: the spring-core is the critical one. For sure you have compiled with the one you say. Runtime is different: print the tomcat classpath. somehow you are loading an older (really older!) version. Perhaps the one you were using before.